# symfony controller sends duplicate values in embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, duplicates

I'm using an embedded form with Symfony 2.8 but I have a problem with my controller, it sends blank values between valid values. Any idea?. Thanks

This is what twig recives:

[This is what twig recives:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DccHn.png)

The result:

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlTsp.png)

In my controller:

```
        public function editarDetalleAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $id = $session->get('id');

    $detalles = $em->getRepository('ComponentesBundle:Receta_detalle')->findRecetaPorId($id);
    $recetaDetalles = new Receta_detalle();

    foreach ($detalles as $detalle){
        $ingrediente = $detalle->getIngrediente();
        $recetaDetalles->getDetalles()->add($detalle->setIngrediente($ingrediente));

        $gramaje = $detalle->getGramaje();
        $recetaDetalles->getDetalles()->add($detalle->setGramaje($gramaje));
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new Receta_detalleCollectionType(), $recetaDetalles);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
 //             $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('ComponentesBundle:Backend:receta/edit_detalle.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
 }
```

My parent form:

```
namespace ComponentesBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class Receta_detalleType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('ingrediente')
    ->add('gramaje')
//         ->add('receta')        
        ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'ComponentesBundle\Entity\Receta_detalle'
    ));
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'componentesbundle_receta_detalle';
}
}
```

My embedded form:

```
namespace ComponentesBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use ComponentesBundle\Entity\Receta_detalle;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class Receta_detalleCollectionType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
   ->add('detalles', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type'=> Receta_detalleType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,

        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_name' => 'detalles__name__',

   ))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'ComponentesBundle\Entity\Receta_detalle'
    ));
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'componentesbundle_receta_detalleCollection';
}
}
```

And my view:

```
<h3>Detalle</h3>

{{ form_start(form) }}
{% for detail in form.detalles %}
    {{ form_row(detail.ingrediente) }}
    {{ form_row(detail.gramaje) }}  
{% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Editar" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Just what is `$x = $detalle->getX(); [...]->add($detalle->setX($x))` supposed to do? You get the property and set it on the same object - why? (x being a placeholder for Ingediente and Gramaje here). I suspect your setters return the object itself (eg. `return $this;` at the end of them). Your foreach code then boils down to: `foreach ($detalles as $detalle) { $recetaDetalles->getDetalles()->add($detalle); $recetaDetalles->getDetalles()->add($detalle); }` (eg. adding the same object twice)

Comment: @ccKep Kep is right, you already have an array of recipe objects in your $detale variable, and you attempted to rebuild the same structure in a foreach loop, just build the form with $detalles and see. If that doesn't work, send detalles and recettaDetalles to twig and do a twig dump so we can see what the data looks like.

Comment: Also: Looking at the screenshot, I suppose your `Recata_detalle::setIngediente` method returns `null` (since every 2nd entry is null, starting with the 1st) and thus you add `null` to your array every loop. Long story short: Post your `Recata_detalle` mappings and the `setIngediente` + `setGramaje` methods.

Comment: thanks so much ccKep and Marko Zivkovic. You are right, I have changed the foreach loop as indicated me ccKep and It works